# How do we determine the flow regime during condensation without knowing the Reynolds number?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow, turbulence, condensation

Condensation occurs in the mixed flow regime of a condensate film on a flat vertical plate. How does one determine the flow regime during condensation without knowing the Reynolds number? I know that there is an simpler way than calculating the Reynolds number.

Comment: If you know that there is a simpler way, why are you asking this question?

Comment: because i'm aware of it existance, but i don't know it exactly...

Comment: What's wrong with assuming that it is laminar and then subsequently calculating the Reynolds Number to check on that?

Comment: fine by me, but not for my fluid dynamics professor, he said, that there is simple and easy way to determine flow regime then assumption and Reynolds number.